# NHibernate full text search documentation

Tags: nhibernate, full-text-search

For the net release of our software we want to offer our customers some form of full-text search or faceted search.

Our ORM is NHibernate 3.1.

There is plenty of Google hits for NHibernate 3.1 + search + documentation.

However not a single one that I found leads to a structured document with the straight dope on search in NHibernate.

Where's the docu at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether there is official documentation but I have used [this](http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/03/04/Nhibernate-Search-Tutorial-with-LuceneNet-and-NHibernate-30.aspx) in the past to get the basics up and running

Also, there is a book if you are interested :) [book](http://www.manning.com/bernard/)

Comment: http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/03/04/Nhibernate-Search-Tutorial-with-LuceneNet-and-NHibernate-30.aspx deals with Lucene not NHibernate Search although that appears to be using Lucene as a basis.
If I start using software like to be able to RTFM, but it looks like there is no "beeep" manual.

Comment: I did accept your answer as there really doesn't seem to be any thing better, thanks. I think we will go with the build in Full Text of SQL Server.